# error with usage of variables in regular expression (match) in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

what is going wrong with the below code?

Even if I pass the value as `"aa"` or `"a"`, `matchingArray` is null.

Probably something is going wrong with the usage of variable in the regular expression.

```
var gEnLowercase = "a-z";
var gLanguageLowercase = "([" + gEnLowercase + "]";
gLanguageLowercase = gLanguageLowercase + "{0 , " + aLength + "})";
var filter = new RegExp(gLanguageLowercase);
var matchingArray = aValue.match(filter); // filter value => /([a-z]{0,10})/
```

Comment: try to use this: `var matchingArray = filter.match(aValue);`

Answer (score 1):

remove the extra space after 0 in the gLanguageLowercase ...it should be

```
gLanguageLowercase = gLanguageLowercase + "{0," + aLength + "})";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var gEnLowercase = "a-z";
var gLanguageLowercase = "([" + gEnLowercase + "]";
gLanguageLowercase = gLanguageLowercase + "{0," + 3 + "})";
var filter = new RegExp(gLanguageLowercase);
console.log(filter);
var matchingArray = "sds".match(filter);
console.log(matchingArray);
```

remove the extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `filter.exec(aValue);` instead of `aValue.match(filter);` Besides there are extra spaces in your regexp.

```
var gEnLowercase = "a-z";
var aLength = 10;
var gLanguageLowercase = "([" + gEnLowercase + "]";
gLanguageLowercase = gLanguageLowercase + "{0," + aLength + "})";
var filter = new RegExp(gLanguageLowercase);
var matchingArray = filter.exec(aValue); // filter value => /([a-z]{0,10})/
```